# Docker doesn't write poetry.lock and requirements on build image

Tags: docker, docker-compose, python-poetry

I'm trying to create an image with Python + Poetry.

However, after executing `poetry install`, I demand that the **Dockerfile** generate a `poetry.lock` and then generate a `requirements.txt` in order to appear in my project root these files, however, it does not happen .

**Dockerfile:**

```
WORKDIR /code

RUN pip install "poetry==$POETRY_VERSION"
RUN poetry config virtualenvs.create false

COPY pyproject.toml poetry.lock* /code/

RUN poetry install --no-root
RUN poetry lock --no-update
RUN poetry export --format=requirements.txt > requirements.txt

COPY . /code/
```

If I take these same commands and execute them directly inside the container after the build, it works normally and then I can access the generated files.

```
$ poetry lock --no-update
Skipping virtualenv creation, as specified in config file.
Updating dependencies
Resolving dependencies... (0.2s)

Writing lock file
```

Comment: Apparently the problem was with the COPY . /code, as I took all my files from the root (without the poetry.lock and requirements) and replaced the content inside the container.

Comment: This flow seems inverted to me – I'd expect the version lock file to be checked into your source tree and be an _input_ into the build process, not an output.  It looks like you `COPY` the file into the image; why do you need to regenerate it?

Comment: In fact, my goal was to install the dependencies from pyproject.toml and then make poetry.lock available.

But, in the end, I decided to remove these steps at build time and threw these commands to a Makefile

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in my `docker-compose.yml` where there was a "bind" of volumes that did all the replacement inside the container removing the files generated during the build.

```
web:
    volumes:
      - .:/code
```

That is, during the build the files were generated, however, when the container was uploaded via `compose`, the local files (which did not have the `poetry.lock` or the `requirements.txt` ) were replaced inside the container, giving to understand this problem.